# Create csv out of a file that has three columns with bash

Tags: bash, csv, scripting

I'm newer with bash scripting. I have a regular txt file with three columns of data. I want to make this into csv format.

```
hagabe   3322   7/28/14
uenebh   3878   7/26/14
jheheb   5569   7/27/14
```

Making it look like:

```
hagabe,3322,7/28/14
```

I know I could take each column and make a file then use paste to create the csv but that seems like over kill. There has to be an easier way. Would it be logical to simply remove the spaces and add the comas? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Assuming the data is tab delimited: `tr '\t' ','`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `awk` with `OFS` set to `,`:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
hagabe,3322,7/28/14
uenebh,3878,7/26/14
jheheb,5569,7/27/14
```

Comment: This is the idiomatic awk answer. The odd-looking `$1=$1` is there to force awk to re-format the line using the output field separator. The `NF` condition is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ +/,",")}1' file
hagabe,3322,7/28/14
uenebh,3878,7/26/14
jheheb,5569,7/27/14
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your file though sed:

```
cat <file> | sed 's/[ ]\+/,/g'
```

Comment: `cat <file> | sed 's/[ ]\+/,/g'` or shorter `sed 's/[ ]\+/,/g' <file>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat in
hagabe   3322   7/28/14
uenebh   3878   7/26/14
jheheb   5569   7/27/14

$ while read -ra line; do IFS=, eval echo \"\${line[*]}\"; done <in
hagabe,3322,7/28/14
uenebh,3878,7/26/14
jheheb,5569,7/27/14
```